# Oculus Mobile Samples crash on startup

Tags: android, android-ndk, oculus

When building and running the samples included with the Oculus Mobile SDK the app crashes on startup. When I try to install and run the prebuilt apk files included with the SDK everything is working as expected. I have read that I should add the Oculus signature in the /assets/ folder which I did but still I end up with a crashing application on startup.

I think the crash is caused by the following:

```
01-22 14:28:52.190    2292-2338/com.oculussdk.oculus360videos A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000008f4 (code=-6), thread 2338 (OVR::VrThread)
```

The only fix i can read about is including the signature file that must be generated via the website, which i did.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit:

So i have tried comparing the two apks the one that i built and the one that was prebuilt, by extracting them as a zip file.

The only noticable difference is that my build contains a oculussig_xxxxx file inside the /assets folder
The apk that comes prebuilt with the sdk does not contain this file however it does contain a OCOLUS.OSIG file located in the META-INF folder. Is this where possibly the problem lies?

Also upon running the apk that i am trying to build logcat notices me with the following:

VRManager was not found. This is weird in my opnion since VrLib is in the package.

my apk:
[image]

prebuilt apk that comes with mobile sdk
[image]

Comment: Is that the entire stack trace? Are you using the same version of the NDK and same target API as the prebuilt samples were built with?

Comment: it also says VRmanager not found. I have decrompessed both of the apks. The only noticable difference is that my apk contains a oculussig_xxxx file and the the apk that comes with the samples. does not instead it contains a OCULUS.OSIG file in the META-INF directory.